# maze solver using BFS process time

Tags: c#

I have been trying to solve a maze using BFS.

I have written the code in python, and I am using the same concept to solve it, but it takes way longer time to process it. For 441x441 maze, it takes about 5~10minutes.

Here is my code

```
        public static List<Tuple<int, int>> BFS(List<List<Tuple<byte, byte, byte>>> list, Tuple<int, int> startPixel, Tuple<int, int> endPixel, int width, int height)
        {
            var startPixelList = new List<Tuple<int, int>> { startPixel };
            var endPixelList = new List<Tuple<int, int>> { endPixel };

            Queue<List<Tuple<int, int>>> Q = new Queue<List<Tuple<int, int>>> { };
            Q.Enqueue(startPixelList);

            Tuple<byte, byte, byte> black = Tuple.Create(Convert.ToByte(0), Convert.ToByte(0), Convert.ToByte(0));
            list[startPixel.Item1][startPixel.Item2] = black;

            while (Q.Count != 0)
            {
                var path = Q.Dequeue();
                var pathClone = DeepClone(path);
                var pixel = path[path.Count - 1];
                if (pixel.Item1 == endPixel.Item1 && pixel.Item2 == endPixel.Item2)
                {
                    return path;
                }
                Tuple<int, int> pixelLeft = getLeftPixel(pixel.Item1, pixel.Item2);
                Tuple<int, int> pixelRight = getRightPixel(pixel.Item1, pixel.Item2);
                Tuple<int, int> pixelTop = getTopPixel(pixel.Item1, pixel.Item2);
                Tuple<int, int> pixelBottom = getBottomPixel(pixel.Item1, pixel.Item2);
                int leftX = pixelLeft.Item1;
                int leftY = pixelLeft.Item2;
                int rightX = pixelRight.Item1;
                int rightY = pixelRight.Item2;
                int topX = pixelTop.Item1;
                int topY = pixelTop.Item2;
                int bottomX = pixelBottom.Item1;
                int bottomY = pixelBottom.Item2;
                if (leftX < 0 || leftY < 0 || leftX > width || leftY > height)
                {

                }
                //check if it is white
                else if (checkWhite(list[leftX][leftY]))
                {
                    list[leftX][leftY] = black; //set the pixel to black so we would not visit again
                    var temp = DeepClone(pathClone);
                    path = temp;
                    path.Add(pixelLeft);
                    Q.Enqueue(path);
                }
                if (rightX < 0 || rightY < 0 || rightX > width || rightY > height)
                {

                }
                else if (checkWhite(list[rightX][rightY]))
                {
                    var temp = DeepClone(pathClone);
                    path = temp;
                    path.Add(pixelRight);
                    Q.Enqueue(path);
                }

                if (topX < 0 || topY < 0 || topX > width || topY > height)
                {

                }
                else if (checkWhite(list[topX][topY]))
                {
                    list[topX][topY] = black; //set the pixel to black so we would not visit again
                    var temp = DeepClone(pathClone);
                    path = temp;
                    path.Add(pixelTop);
                    Q.Enqueue(path);
                }

                if (bottomX < 0 || bottomY < 0 || bottomX > width || bottomY > height)
                {

                }
                else if (checkWhite(list[bottomX][bottomY]))
                {
                    list[bottomX][bottomY] = black; //set the pixel to black so we would not visit again
                    var temp = DeepClone(pathClone);
                    path = temp;
                    path.Add(pixelBottom);
                    Q.Enqueue(path);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Path not found");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Basically my list that has RGB values for each pixel is

List>>, 2-D list that has tuple in it, so list[i][j] where i is width # and j is height #.

BFS takes the whole list, starting pixel, ending pixel, width of image and height of image.

I am dequeueing the starting pixel which is a list of tuple, and find left,right,top,bottom (adjacent) pixels and see if it is white. If it is white, I am appending each pixel to the original path, then enqueueing them back.

I think my problem is because I am deepcloning my path list. I am creating a deep copy of path because each time I append the adjacent pixels, original path is deleted. I need original path in order to check for right, top, and bottom. (If that makes any sense)

For example, if I have pixel starting at (51,5), I check for left which is (50,5) and if it is white, I append it to the original path, so I enqueue [(51,5),(50,5)]. But if I want to check right of the pixel, I need original path pixel (51,5), not the updated path. So I deep clone (because c# uses pointer) to maintain original pixel.

Please help me how to make this code more efficient and faster than I have right now. I am using Bitmap to obtain RGB values for each pixels.

Comment: so the question is - why is this code so slow, but you did not provide all the code - checkWhite,DeepClone,.... Did you try putting stopwatches in to at least see how long sections of the code take?

Comment: seeing this `List<List<Tuple<byte, byte, byte>>> list` sets off all sorts of alarms for me. Its a very unnatural c# structure, python maybe, c# not so much.

Comment: 1. Use a profiler. 2. If you're using `Bitmap.GetPixel` in a tight loop, I suggest you look into `LockBits` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you enter a maze and pick only one side(left wall or right wall) and follow that path it will take you to exit. Obviously it will not give you the shortest path. But only the pixels you walk over twice are makes the path longer so just get rid off them.

I hope this will be helpful.